# Undefined properties when looping through API Data

Tags: reactjs, undefined, typeerror

I have a function that retrieves data from an API and returns a JSON format of information. I am trying to loop through it and retrieve parts of the data, however I get an type error saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'championId')"

```
const { Title } = Typography;

const Homepage = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState({});
  const [playerStats, setPlayerStats] = useState({});
  const [champStats, setChampStats] = useState({});

  const API_KEY = "MYAPI";

  function searchForPlayer(event) {
    var APICallSummoner =
      "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" +
      searchText +
      "?api_key=" +
      API_KEY;

    axios
      .get(APICallSummoner)
      .then(function (response) {
        setPlayerData(response.data);
        if (response.data) {
          searchPlayerData(response.data.id);
          searchChampion(response.data.id);
          Rend();
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  function searchChampion(id) {
    var API =
      "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/champion-mastery/v4/champion-masteries/by-summoner/" +
      id +
      "?api_key=" +
      API_KEY;

    axios
      .get(API)
      .then(function (response) {
        setChampStats(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  function searchPlayerData(id) {
    var API =
      "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/" +
      id +
      "?api_key=" +
      API_KEY;

    axios
      .get(API)
      .then(function (response) {
        setPlayerStats(response.data[1]);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  function Rend() {
    const cham = [];
    console.log(championNames[champStats[0].championId]);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      cham.push(championNames[champStats[i].championId]);
    }

    return <>{cham}</>;
  }

  // Total Games Played
  const total = playerStats.wins + playerStats.losses;
  const rank = playerStats.tier + " " + playerStats.rank;

  return (
    <>
      <Title level={2} className='heading'>
        LoLTracker
      </Title>
      <input
        type='text'
        onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          searchForPlayer(e);
        }}>
        Search Player
      </button>
      {JSON.stringify(playerData) != "{}" &&
      JSON.stringify(playerStats) != "{}" ? (
        <>
          <h1>{playerData.name}</h1>
          <img
            width='100'
            height='100'
            src={
              "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.3.1/img/profileicon/" +
              playerData.profileIconId +
              ".png"
            }></img>
          <p>Summoner Level: {playerData.summonerLevel} </p>
          <Row>
            <Col span={12}>
              <Statistic title='Solo/Duo Games Played' value={total} />
            </Col>
            <Col span={12}>
              <Statistic title='Current Rank' value={rank} />
            </Col>
            <Col span={12}>
              <Statistic title='Solo/Duo Wins' value={playerStats.wins} />
            </Col>
            <Col span={12}>
              <Statistic title='Solo/Duo Losses' value={playerStats.losses} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <div className='home-heading-container'>
            <Title level={2} className='home-title'>
              Most Played Champions
            </Title>
          </div>

          <Rend />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <h1>There is no data for this player, INACTIVE</h1>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

It is in my Rend(), function. championNames is my own JSON file I created that retrieves the name of a character from its ID. How can I loop through the data to display what I want?

````
at Rend (Homepage.jsx:77:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)"
 Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    at Homepage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:243:86)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:61578:5)
    at div
    at section
    at BasicLayout (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6383:63)
    at Adapter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6351:66)
    at div
    at div
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:61511:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60991:5```


Thanks
````

Comment: What is the full error message? And which line causes the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'championId'  and also react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function @Code-Apprentice, the error is on line 77 and 243

Comment: Please [edit] your question so you can format the error message for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` for some champ. Try ignoring it somehow. Here is an example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  
  champStats[i].championId ?
   cham.push(championNames[champStats[i].championId]) : null
}
```

My theory is that some champ in the iteration from 0 to 10 does not exist.

Comment: I've tried this, however the same problem happens. Even when I iterate through the entire champion list, it still says undefined